# cups integration ios/tvOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, tvos

I am trying to integrate cups library for print. I created one static library for iOS/tvOS using cups, jpege etc and i build the library. When i try to integrate it with my project and try to run by calling the functionalities inside the static library it shows some error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "__ppdParseOptions",
>   referenced from:
>         __ppdCacheCreateWithPPD in mylib.a(ppd-cache.o)   "_ppdFindAttr", referenced from: 
>   __ppdCacheCreateWithPPD in mylib.a(ppd-cache.o)

Please help me on this.

Comment: The library doesn't support Simulator Versions. x86_64 is MAC architecture. You can run on the physical device.

Comment: Now i am using cups version v2.1.4. Previously i used v1.6.2 and it works well in tvOS simulator. Now i upgrade.

Comment: Please share the URL to the cups library.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/cups/releases/tag/release-2.1.4

Comment: I tried compiling v2.1.4, it is trowing errors. I used 2.2.1, it is working fine.

Comment: Ok thanks for you support.. will check and inform you